# How to query titan graph with gremlin queries based on integer properties

Tags: rest, groovy, graph-databases, titan, gremlin

I have multiple nodes in a titan graph server with integer properties, I want to query the graph based on integer properties, the server is configured with REST so I'm querying the graph this way:

```
titan-server:8182/gremlin=Query 
(e.g Query could be : g.V().hasLabel("Person"))
```

I want to fetch all person vertices with `age = 30` (just an example)

This can be done in gremlin console (socket based) as follow:
`g.V().hasLabel("Person").has("age",30);`

but this doesn't work on rest query, it give an empty results (even if there is such a vertex with `age = 30` ):

```
titan-server:8182/gremlin=g.V().hasLabel("Person")**.has("age",30)**;
```

I didn't find any docs over the internet for gremlin on rest.

Thank you for help guys

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get the REST API to work by doing the following. First, as specified [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_connecting_via_rest) make sure to change the channel in the `gremlin-server.yaml` config to:

```
channelizer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.HttpChannelizer
```

Then try the following post:

```
{ 
    "gremlin" : "g.V().hasLabel(x).has(y,z)",
    "bindings" : 
    {
        "x" : "Person",
        "y" : "age",
        "z" : 30
    }
}
```

More info on the REST API can be found [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_connecting_via_rest)